# How to make Google Drive save files “locally” on an external drive?

Tags: finder, imac, external-disk, google-apps

I have my own Google Drive and also a shared drive from my organization.

Upon install and log in, I'm able to move what’s in my own Google Drive to an external drive where I can access files and everything.

The shared drive, on the other hand, is shown in my "Locations". If I mark anything for offline access, it gets downloaded on to the computer’s (iMac) internal disk (SSD).

I want avoid this in order to avoid wear and tear of the SSD, and also, there isn't enough space for it all. **Can I somehow make Google Drive use a different path for streaming/saving files?**

Currently, they are being saved to `/Users/me/Library/CloudStorage/` which is on the computer’s internal drive. Yet, Google Drive reports in its settings "Folder location is controlled by macOS."

I was thinking of hardlinking that path to a location on the external drive, but I don’t want to mess it up as I am not sure if that would work properly.

Comment: Exactly where or when do you get the message "Folder location is controlled by macOS"?

Comment: In google drive's settings.

Answer (score 2):

An illustration here of where one sees the message "Folder location is controlled by macOS", within google drive's settings.

[image: screenshot: "Folder location is controlled by macOS"]

Answer (score 0):

This requires you to mirror your entire drive but it appears to work.

1. Go to Google Drive Preferences.
2. Navigate to Google Drive(Folders from Drive) > My Drive syncing options.
3. Change the setting from 'Stream files' to 'Mirror files'
4. Change the save location to the desired folder on your external drive.